# Drawing lines from ViewModel TornadoFX

Tags: kotlin, drawing, tornadofx

So I got a ViewModel containing Lines (that is 2 point objects that both have an x and y double property). I want to bind this to some canvas or something a like. Furthermore, it could be that lines are not added incrementally to the ViewModel, but all in one time (e.g. when loading an external file that contains a lot of lines data).

How can you solve this with TornadoFX? Moreover, how to make it run smoothly even with a lot of line data. Is it possible with gui builders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple bindChildren fixes it:

```
stackpane {
    group {
        bindChildren(model.segments) { segment ->
            line(segment.first.x, segment.first.y, segment.second.x, segment.second.y)
        }
    }
}
```

In the model, the declaration of the segments:

```
val segments: ObservableList<Segment> = FXCollections.observableArrayList<Segment>()
```